# XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhiteSpace or XmlDocument.PreserveWhiteSpace does not work on \n "

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I have an XML document where it is reading "\n  " as child nodes.  I am trying to remove this using:

```
XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhiteSpace = True
```

or

```
XmlDocument.PreserveWhiteSpace = False
```

but it is not working. The childnode after body is read as "\n   " instead of `<C></C>`  Here is a snippet of code:

```
Dim xrsSettings As New XmlReaderSettings()
xrsSettings.IgnoreComments = True

Dim xrReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(context.Request.InputStream, xrsSettings)
Dim xdRequest As New XmlDocument()
xdRequest.Load(xrReader)
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <C xmlns="http://www.sdfsfsfs.com/3939" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MessageContentCode="8" TimeStamp="2012-05-18T08:32:42" Version="6.000">
      <A HC="ABCD">
        <B CC="EUR" End="2012-06-30" IAI="false" IC="0" MC="P1" RPC="BAR" RPT="Overlay" Start="2012-05-18" YI="false">
          <RS>
            <R CC="EUR" ITC="DR">
              <BBGAS>
                <BBGA AQC="10" AAT="300" NOG="1" />
                <BBGA AQC="10" AAT="300" NOG="2" />
                <BBGA AQC="10" AAT="300" NOG="3" />
              </BBGAS>
            </R>
          </RS>
          <D N="Short">
            <T L="DE">BAR</T>
          </D>
        </B>
      </A>
    </C>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is correct.  If there is no DTD (doctype declaration) specified in the XML, whitespace [is not ignorable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73083/Common-Pitfalls-in-System-Xml-4-0).  [Read here](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch06s10.html) to learn more about parsing modes and ignorable white space.

Although it may appear that you need to introduce a DTD to resolve your problem, I'd rather focus on why you cannot skip the whitespace at a higher level (later in your application) which is the standard approach when dealing with pretty printed XML.